# Creating Ageing report (>0), (0-30), (31-60)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write an Ageing Report on SQL Server which shows the total amount of overdue invoices (later on I will have to deduct Credit Notes) that fall in the different columns depending on how many days the have been overdued. I.e (>0), (0-30), (31-60), (61-90), etc.

This is the part of the query I have written so far mostly looking at old post in this forum but it's giving me a lot of duplicates even for Accounts where there is not due balance.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

> ```
> SELECT O.cardcode      AS [Account],
>        O.cardname      AS [Name],
>        O.u_creditlimit AS [Credit Limit],
>        O.u_onhold      AS [On Hold],
>        O.balance,
>        Isnull(CASE
>                 WHEN Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) >= 0 AND Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) < 30 
>                 THEN (
>                        SELECT Sum(doctotal)
>                        FROM   oinv
>                        WHERE cardcode = INV.cardcode)
>               END, 0)  AS [0 to 30 Days],
>        Isnull(CASE
>                 WHEN Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) >= 31 AND Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) < 60 
>                 THEN (
>                       SELECT Sum(doctotal)
>                       FROM   oinv
>                       WHERE cardcode = INV.cardcode)
>               END, 0)  AS [31 to 60 Days],
>        Isnull(CASE
>                 WHEN Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) >= 61 AND Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) < 90 
>                 THEN (
>                       SELECT Sum(doctotal)
>                       FROM   oinv
>                       WHERE cardcode = INV.cardcode)
>               END, 0)  AS [61 to 90 Days],
>        Isnull(CASE
>                 WHEN Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) >= 91 AND Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) < 120 
>                 THEN (
>                       SELECT Sum(doctotal)
>                       FROM   oinv
>                       WHERE  cardcode = INV.cardcode)
>               END, 0)  AS [91 to 120 Days],
>        Isnull(CASE
>                 WHEN Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) >= 121 
>                 THEN(
>                       SELECT Sum(doctotal)
>                       FROM oinv
>                       WHERE cardcode = INV.cardcode)
>               END, 0)  AS [121+ Days]
> FROM   ocrd O
>        INNER JOIN oinv INV
>                ON O.cardcode = INV.cardcode
> WHERE  territory = 3
>        AND INV.docstatus = 'O'
> ```
>
> Thank you very much.

Comment: There are holes between your ranges; 30, 60 and 90 are clearly being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean this up a bit

First. use a CROSS APPLY to calculate the Days-Past-Due once, and then a conditional aggregation for the final results

**Example (Untested)**

```
  Select O.cardcode
        ,O.cardname  
        ,[Credit Limit]   = max(O.u_creditlimit)
        ,[On Hold]        = max(O.u_onhold)
        ,[0 to 30 Days]   = sum( case when DPD between  0 and  30 then doctotal else 0 end)
        ,[31 to 60 Days]  = sum( case when DPD between 31 and  60 then doctotal else 0 end)
        ,[61 to 90 Days]  = sum( case when DPD between 61 and  90 then doctotal else 0 end)
        ,[91 to 120 Days] = sum( case when DPD between 91 and 120 then doctotal else 0 end)
        ,[121+ Days ]     = sum( case when DPD >=121              then doctotal else 0 end)
   From  ocrd O
   Join  oinv INV on O.cardcode = INV.cardcode
   Cross Apply (values ( Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) ) ) P(DPD)
   Where territory = 3
     and INV.docstatus = 'O' 
     and DPD >= 0
  Group By O.cardcode
          ,O.cardname
```

**EDIT - CREDIT NOTES**

Without sample data or structures here is my GUESS

```
  Select O.cardcode
        ,O.cardname  
        ,[Credit Limit]   = max(O.u_creditlimit)
        ,[On Hold]        = max(O.u_onhold)
        ,[0 to 30 Days]   = sum( case when DPD between  0 and  30 then doctotal - isnull(creditnotes,0) else 0 end)
        ,[31 to 60 Days]  = sum( case when DPD between 31 and  60 then doctotal - isnull(creditnotes,0) else 0 end)
        ,[61 to 90 Days]  = sum( case when DPD between 61 and  90 then doctotal - isnull(creditnotes,0) else 0 end)
        ,[91 to 120 Days] = sum( case when DPD between 91 and 120 then doctotal - isnull(creditnotes,0) else 0 end)
        ,[121+ Days ]     = sum( case when DPD >=121              then doctotal - isnull(creditnotes,0) else 0 end)
   From  ocrd O
   Join  oinv INV on O.cardcode = INV.cardcode
   LEFT JOIN CREDITNOTESTable CN ON O.cardcode = CN.cardcode
   Cross Apply (values ( Datediff(day, INV.docduedate, Getdate()) ) ) P(DPD)
   Where territory = 3
     and INV.docstatus = 'O' 
     and DPD >= 0
  Group By O.cardcode
          ,O.cardname
```

Comment: Hi @John,
Sorry to bother again, as I mentioned in the initial post I am trying to deduct the Credit notes against the invoices that the Clients might have received. The way I am trying to achieve this is using an UNION between the two queries. The table for Credit Notes (ORIN) is identical to the table that contains the data about Invoices (OINV).

But once again I get two different lines per client, one line is the invoices and the other are the Credit notes instead of merging the results... 
Would you have a different way to achieve this instead of using the UNION operator? 
Thanks

Comment: @LMarGonz See EDIT.   This is just a guess .   Note the LEFT JOIN and isnull()

Comment: Thanks once again, if this helps, I found the structure of those two tables in SAP B1 documentation.
Credit notes - ORIN https://sap.erpref.com/?schema=BusinessOne9.3&table=ORIN
Invoice notes - OINV https://sap.erpref.com/?schema=BusinessOne9.3&table=OINV
I swear I am not being lazy, this is all really new to me and I am still learning, yesterday took me 7 min to figure out how to mark you respond as the correct Answer.. same with SQL. At work there isn't anyone who can help me and this is  me fighting with queries way above my knowledge, so I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: I have tried using a Left join before commenting again but the total ammount result of the diff between Invoives - Credit Notes increased by thousands of pounds as supposed to decrease by a couple of hundreds only. When I get home this evening I will try to figure it out how to upload a sample of data in my original post.

Comment: @LMarGonz 2 decades working for a tier-1 bank, I have never seen such ridiculous structures...  this borders on insanity.   Perhaps create an subset of the desired credits and join that into your results.   Take is step-by-step.  When your're happy, move on to the next layer.

Answer (score 0):

when asking questions is a great idea to provide demo data, and a better one to provide it as an object we can easily re recreate:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (RecordID INT IDENTITY, CardCode INT, CardName NVARCHAR(100), u_CreditLimit DECIMAL(10,2), u_onhold DECIMAL(10,2), balance DECIMAL(10,2))
INSERT INTO @table (CardCode, CardName, u_CreditLimit, u_onhold, balance) VALUES (1, 'John Smith', 10000, 0, 200),
(1, 'John Smith', 10000, 0, 400),
(1, 'John Smith', 10000, 0, 200)
```

This would allow someone to just run the TSQL to create and populate the object.

Now using that object we could write something like

```
SELECT RecordID, CardCode, CardName, U_CreditLimit, U_OnHold, Balance, COALESCE(LAG(Balance,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CardCode ORDER BY RecordID) - Balance,Balance) AS RunningTotal
  FROM @table
```

This psudeo code, and may need some tweaking to get exactly what you're looking for.

A quick word on LAG and its pal LEAD. You specify a column and an offset in rows. LAG looks backwards, LEAD forwards. They both use over clauses just like any other windowed function.